# How to do store algebraic data type in persistent

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

For a data type like so

```
data Tree = Node String Tree Tree
          | Leaf String
```

And real data like so

```
my_tree = (Node "first node" (Leaf "leaf") (Node "second node" (Leaf "leaf") (Leaf "leaf")))
```

How do I store that into database using persistent, specifically how to do the "OR" part?

I've tried defining the model like so

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
    Tree
        value String
        leftTree Leaf
        rightTree Leaf
        deriving Show
    Leaf
        value String
        deriving Show
|]
```

The recursive structure would be stored in a column in a row as a json string automatically which is very nice.  But how do we or can we define a "OR" structure in the persistent model?

Comment: If your problem requires storage of such complex data, maybe it will be more convenient to use acid-state instead?

Comment: Ditto.  I'm experimenting with migrating [reffit](http://www.reffit.com) from acid-state to perstent to save memory.  As a newbie to SQL, I was surprised at the austerity of the types that actually go into the database.  I had to turn all my list-typed record fields 'inside out'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Persistent can only store ADTs that have no child data. I.E. the following can be stored:

```
data Tag = Leaf | Fork
```

But recursive structures like this cannot be stored without serialising it to JSON:

```
data Tree a = (Leaf a) | Fork (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

What you have to understand is that Persistent is a type save layer over the top of a database, so you have to think about your schema in terms of what is efficient to store in a database, not in terms of what's a convenient Haskell datastructure.

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
    Tree
        parent TreeId Maybe
        value String
        deriving Show
|]
```

This schema will give you the equivalent of the following structure.

```
data Tree a = Value a [Tree a]
```

Comment: Do you mean "no recursive child data"? So that e.g. `data Tag = Leaf Int | Fork String` _can_ be stored?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, you know, I've never tried. I bet it could actually be stored, though it would need to be serialised in some way first, and it's been a while since I looked at that part of the persistent code.

Comment: Yes....I understand in the end its just a layer over database.  I'm just wondering since it is smart enough to change it to json, can it also help keep the structure of a data type with "OR"???  If so how to define it in the model? Or like you wrote the tree is a maybe and the leaf will always be there?

Comment: Also, how does the `parent TreeId Maybe` translate to a list of maybe Trees?

Comment: @HCC this is a reverse relation, meaning that many Tree rows can refer to a parent Tree row. Thus when writing this as an ADT and expression it as a forward relationship, we represent it as list of tree. Just think, each node can only have one parent, but can have many children.

Comment: @Thomas I see now thank!  So could I do "OR"? Or I'll have to use maybe for if it's a tree or leaf thus not giving the nice constraints of the original data type?